# How to count occurrences character in the string

Tags: c#-4.0, c#-3.0

i have a string like "Nitin" write a method or logic to get output like this 
N=2 I=2 T=1 
means char count in string.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
        string input= "asdjhrituerjkfdgf";

        var resultList= input.GroupBy(e => e).Select(g => new { g.Key, Count = g.Count() }).ToList() ;
```

Comment: Bravo !!! Nice !!! Just one line of code.